# Plotting remotely using mayavi and python

Tags: python, remote-server, mayavi

I have a massive file I need to parse and render on a remote machine, I already have scripts written using mayavi to do exactly this.  What I'd like to do is save the image as a png and then copy the image over and view it locally.  This is pretty simple to do with matplotlib by setting the backend to 'Agg', however I'm having some serious problems doing this with mayavi.  I've followed the guide here

http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html

but the problem is that importing mlab alone *requires* access to the xdisplay, so I can't even turn on the virtual window as suggested.

To reproduce this, access a machine through ssh and run a simple python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from mayavi import mlab
```

and it will error out with the standard;

> Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

If anyone has a fix for this, or an alternative route to rendering a 3D image remotely I'd appreciate it.  The 3D rendering provided by matplotlib is insufficient for what I need so any suggestions for working alternatives to mayavi would be appreciated as well.

Comment: removed matplotlib tag as this is not related to matplotlib.

Comment: Have you check the tips about the virtual framebuffer ? http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#rendering-using-the-virtual-framebuffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a *nix platform running an X server, use the solution in the documentation under [rendering using the virtual framebuffer](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#rendering-using-the-virtual-framebuffer%20%22rendering%20using%20the%20virtual%20framebuffer%22.) as dpinte commented above. I have used this method successfully before to run mayavi scripts headlessly.

The basic idea is to start a virtual X server such as Xvfb, and then invoke mayavi in the display context of the virtual X server (and yes this explanation is not quite right, but it will suffice).

Comment: OK This seems to generate a whole new slew of errors so I was hesitant to move forward with it. I suppose those problems are cause for a new question.  Thanks for the help though, just knowing this is actually possible to do is helpful.